# Issue with connecting to SQL Server database from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I've created a simple Windows Forms application in C# and now find it hard to connect it to a SQL Server database. I've created the database within Visual Studio itself. However, once I try to insert data I get a SQL exception. My guess is there is problem in the connection data source i.e the con variable. Please help me find a solution.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Database1;Integrated Security=SSPI");

SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter adapt;

if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "")
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [dbo].[user] (Id, username, password) values (@id, @name, @state)", con);

    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", textBox3.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully");
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Provide Details!");
}
```

The database file name is

```
\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.mdf
```

Comment: Can you provide error details when you get SQL exception?

Comment: Additional information: Cannot open database "Database1" requested by the login. The login failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you created the database on an actual instance of SQL Server (this can be a local instance on your machine), it appears as though your connection string's data source isn't quite right.

> Data Source=DESKTOP-XXXXXXX/Shenal Burkey

There are two problems with this, first the slash (/) should actually be a backslash (). Second, after the slash you have 'Shenal Burkey' with a space. SQL Server instance names cannot contain space characters. That being said, if you installed SQL Server as a named instance, you need to specify the named instance in that place, if you accepted the default instance name it should be 'MSSQLSERVER'. If you are using the default instance name, you can either specify your connection string like this:

```
Data Source=DESKTOP-XXXXXXX\MSSQLSERVER
```

or you can omit the instance name entirely and just use:

```
Data Source=DESKTOP-XXXXXXX
```

Also, just a tip, you will notice I replaced the specifics of your DESKTOP's hostname with X's, personally I'd recommend editing your question and doing the same. It may not seem like it would be useful, but someone might just pick that up and find a crafty way to do some damage. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: That seems to work but now I get an error for the database name I've changed it to Database1(name of my database). but still i keep getting an error.                               SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Database1;Integrated Security=SSPI;");